# Tips on killing enemies effectively using the Time Bomb

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm playing Fallout: New Vegas in my 3rd playthrough. The one weapon I've never used is the [Time Bomb](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Time_bomb).

Once armed, you have 15 secs before it goes off. I don't find it useful for:

- normal enemy encounters since it rarely lasted 15 seconds,
- stealth kills,
- boss or deathclaw encounters where they need to stay put

Can anyone suggest effective ways to deploy the Time Bomb to kill enemies?

Answer (score 5):

I found almost all of the timed explosives to be difficult to use and very situational.  I only really used them, and only really tin grenades, in service of Crackerjack Timing as part of my 100% achievement run (which I documented [here](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/new-vegas-100-achievements-guide/)).

Most of the time enemies don't really have strong AI enough to plan where they're going to be in 15 seconds.  (Well, besides the ones that will just run up in your face...) so setting an explosive and having exactly 15 seconds to bring someone into their radius is kind of hard to do.  If someone is standing still or pathing in a consistent pattern, you might be able to measure out 15 seconds and catch them in the blast, but by that point you might as well just shoot them in the face (not the hands, not the legs, etc) and get it over with.

The one situation where it could be interesting is stealth reverse-pickpocketing a live bomb into an enemy's inventory.  This will cause them to become a walking time bomb, and if they're pathing into an area with other hostiles, you might be able to take them all out at once.

Answer (score -1):

I used it during Veronica's quest, when the BOS goons murdered the Followers. Instead of talking to them, I chucked a time bomb in their room, crouched in the furthest corner, and BOOM! Wiped out all three.